# RegEx (.net) to remove first character and everything after the last underscore

Tags: .net, regex

I have this Regex that breaks if there is a - or ~ or = or any special character(s) in the string. Basically, I want to remove the first letter (which is a) and remove everything after the last underscore. (RegEx must be one liner) For example, Tester link http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3da%29%5b%5cw+%5d%2b%28%3f%3d_%29&i=aPersonal+Protective+Equipment_REV2.docx%0d%0aaFreight+Forwarder+Standard+Operating+Procedure+-++Armenia_REV1.docx&o=i

```
(?<=a)[\w ]+(?=_)
```

aPersonal Protective Equipment_REV2.docx - Works for this string (outcome is Personal Protective Equipment)

However fails for following string
aFreight Forwarder Standard Operating Procedure -  Armenia_REV1.docx (outcome is rmenia)

Comment: good catch. i updated the details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
(^.*?(?=a)a)|_[^_]*$
```

The RegEx above worked (Replace and Ignore Cases)

```
asomefile_(rw_340-v4) follow up by_ver2.xlsx
```

result: `somefile_(rw_340-v4) follow up by`

Answer (score 0):

Changing the pattern to this appears to address the issue of the dash:

```
(?<=a)[\w\-=~ ]+(?=_)
```

My test cases:

> aPersonal Protective Equipment_REV2.docx
>   aFreight Forwarder Standard Operating Procedure - Armenia_REV1.docx
>   aFreight Forwarder~~ Standard Operating= Procedure - Armenia_REV1.docx

`\w` matches words.  A dash is a word boundary.. to preserve it you have to match on it as well.

You might consider

```
(?<=^a).+?(?=_.+?$)
```

instead.  You would need multiline mode on if you were going to match more than one item at a time.
This one will match any character between the 1st character and the last underscore.

Comment: thank you sam for the fix. however, it breaks if i put other special characters in the string (for example, = or ~ etc). What do you think?

Comment: It appears to work for me.  Since I can't see what you've tried I can't really provide much help.  I've updated the answer to include `=` and `~`.

Comment: Sam. you are right the code works if there is - or + or ~. however do I need to put all the special characters in the code because if I put ( in the string then it will break. Would it be possible to re-do the code? remove the first character and remove everything after the last underscore.

Comment: Try the edit I just made.  Also, I highly recommend [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com) if you are on Windows.

Comment: http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5ea%29.%2b%3f%28%3f%3d_.%2b%3f%24%29&i=aPersonal+Protective+Equipment_REV2.docx%0d%0aaFreight+Forwarder+Standard+Operating+Procedure+%7e+Armenia_REV1.docx  did it work for you.

Comment: I can't help you if you can't follow instructions.